tabularray's multiline cells and cmd: incompatible?
It doesn't seem possible to combine tabularray's multiline cells and cmd, as shown by the following MCE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[l,cmd=\bfseries]}
    }
    \hline
    foo  \\
    {foo \\foo} \\
  \end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}

which fails to compile, with the unhelpful error message:

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
  for immediate help.
...
l.11   \end
{tblr}
?

Am I missing something?

The macro specified by the cmd key uses the content of a cell as argument.
Here, you can use the font key:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[l,font=\bfseries] Q}
  }
  \hline
  foo         & a \\
  {foo \\foo} & b \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


